# How to inherit parent site look and feel on my Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page, site-template, theme

I have created a subsite but now I want to inherit the look and feel theme from my parent site all the radio button are disabled under **Setting >> Site Settings >> Master Pages** .Is there a way I can enable those radio buttons?

Comment: This may help you - https://chayadigital.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/how-to-enable-theme-inheritance-in-a-site-collection-and-subsites-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: One of the suggested answer suggested that you try to activate the Publishing feature on the subsite you are working on, but you correctly pointed out that you already did that. You also said that the “Inherit theme from the parent of this site” radio buttons are disabled... can you check if the **parent** site is a publishing site and if not enable the feature there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for SharePoint 2010

Please follow the below steps:

- Go to  **root** level

In **Site Collection** >> **Site Actions** >> **Site Settings** >> Site Collection Administration section >> **Site collection features**

There is one feature named **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** >> Click 'Activate' button

- Then go to subsite

**Site Actions** >> **Site Settings** >> **Look and Feel** >> **Site theme**

You can select “Inherit theme from the parent of this site” or “Specify a theme to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it”

Comment: The feature is active,its a team site that I am working on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to Site settings in your team site you have created.

Goto **site settings** >> under **look and feel** >> click on **site theme** >>**inherit theme from parent site**.

find the screen shot below

[image]